# How to handle dependencies when libraries are loaded asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

Google Pagespeed said I should load my JS files asynchronously, but this has introduced a problem for many of my pages with code using libraries and plugins.

For example, I have the following code on one page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hound = new Bloodhound({ .......
});
```

So when the page loads, I am creating a Twitter Bloodhound (goes with Typeahead) object. The problem is, if Bloodhound and Typeahead are loaded asynchronously, then an error is thrown:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Bloodhound is not defined
```

This is because those scripts haven't been loaded yet.

I came up with this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    createBloodhound();
});


function createBloodhound() {
    if (typeof Bloodhound != "undefined") { // if bloodhound JS has loaded
        var hound = new Bloodhound({ .......
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            createBloodhound();
        }, 10);
    }
}
```

Is this a good practice, or is there a better way?

NOTE: I realize there are libraries like RequireJS out there to handle dependencies when loading files, but I don't think this type of solution will not work in my case because I load the libraries asynchronously in a wrapper file (since they're required for every page). The example code here would not be on every page, but only on a specific page on my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is to use a callback mechanism, which you can react to, rather than using a polling mechanism.  I used [script.js](http://www.dustindiaz.com/scriptjs), which is simple and yet functional, and offers the callback mechanism.

Without that, you could implement something yourself.  Performance-wise though, utilizing callback are better.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of your site, different options might be best. If...

1. All of your javascript is in JS files
2. Your above-the-fold content looks identical before and after the JS is loaded (or close enough to identical that the flash of change when your JS does load wouldn't distract your users)
3. The total file size is small (or most of your JS is needed on pages everyone will visit every time they visit your site)

... then combine them into one file and just server that instead of all the individual ones. Then you don't have to worry about dependencies at all. Include that script file at the bottom of your body tag (no need for async or defer attributes, but you can use them if you want).

If some of your javascript is necessary to make your above-the-fold content look correct, do the same thing, except split your JS into two files. One file contains only what is necessary to make the above-the-fold content look correct, and the other file contains everything else. Include the first one in your head tag (possibly inlining it), and include the second one at the bottom of your body tag. If the second one depends on the first tag, do not use the async attribute, because it might get executed first.

If you have some large JS files that are only used on some pages, and those files depend on other JS files, stick your scripts at the bottom of your body tag and use the defer attribute.

If you have javascript mixed in with your HTML, you can use a callback mechanism (like [script.js](http://www.dustindiaz.com/scriptjs)), or you can build up execution queues like Google Analytics does, which the external script knows to look for when it first loads.